# sum multiple dataframes in model

Tags: python, pandas, class

I have build a model for the optimization of my energy consumption.
Some of the variables are given in datasheets.
For simplicity and the availability of different datasheets I build my model inside a class.

The different energy consumptions are defined in the init function of the class:

```
    def __init__(self, PV, refrigerator, clotheswasher, dishwasher, freezer):
        self.PV = PV
        self.refrigerator = refrigerator
        self.clotheswasher = clotheswasher
        self.dishwasher = dishwasher
        self.freezer = freezer
```

These values are used in my model for all timestamps of the data (i.e. one day, every 5 min data)

```
    for t in self.model.T:
        self.model.PV[t] = self.PV
        self.model.refrigerator[t] = self.refrigerator
        self.model.clotheswasher[t] = self.clotheswasher
        self.model.dishwasher[t] = self.dishwasher
        self.model.freezer[t] = self.freezer
```

I want to add them up to make a plot of my total energy consumption of the day

```
    self.model.total[t] = self.model.PV[t] + self.model.refrigerator[t] + self.model.clotheswasher[t] + self.model.dishwasher[t] + self.model.freezer[t]
```

However, by doing so for every `t` in `self.model.total[t]` I get a dataframe with the summations, i.e., when adding A B and C:

```
index   A   B   C   
  1     3   4   2    
  2     2   1   4    
  3     1   3   2
```

I would like to get a dataframe like:

```
index      tot
  1         9
  2         7
  3         6
```

but I get:

```
index      tot
  1         9
            7
            6
  2         9
            7
            6
  3         9
            7
            6
```

can someone help me out?

Comment: Hi Peter, Are you doing that energy summation as the last statement of your for t in self.model.T loop?

Comment: Also, can you show details on how you're loading your data and instantiating your class? Seems like you "might be" doing some type of data duplication through multiple instantiations of your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we simplify what you are trying to do by working on your simplified data example, we could use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

DF = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")

print DF
print 

for i in range(len(DF)):
    print i, sum(DF.iloc[i])
```

which would yield the following output:

```
   A  B  C
0  3  4  2
1  2  1  4
2  1  3  2

0 9
1 7
2 6
```

You are probably just making some simple mistake with your class instantiation and data loading. Once you fix that, your results will likely come out right. Start from a small simple data set until you find your issue, and trouble shoot each step.